# real time identifying where disk is filling up

Tags: disk-usage, monitoring

I have a 5TB RAID volume mounted as `/data` and it is always near 100% full. It is currently at 99% full saying 68GB available via `du -sh`.

It hits 100%, user's can't write to it, we clear some data maybe free up 100GB or so, good for however long.  Process repeats.

My question is, is there a way for me as an admin with root access to identify which folders under my `/data` are being written to the most so that I can get an idea of who or what activity is actively working on the system creating the most data filling up the disk?

It is an XFS file system.  The layout is basically this

```
/data
/data/Project1/
/data/Project2/
/data/Project_n/
/data/users/
/data/users/x001/
/data/users/x002/
/data/users/x00_n/
```

I just want to find which Project# or which user x# folder has been growing as of late.  That's as deep as I need to go into the folder tree under /data.

Comment: Any way to take a snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

Read `man lsof` and do something like

```
sudo lsof +D / data
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will display the disk usage summary of each directory in the **/data/** directory tree.

`# find /data/* -type d -exec du -sh {} \; | sort -hr`

This command will display the 10 largest directories in the **/data/** directory tree.

`# find /data/* -type d -exec du -sh {} \; | sort -hr | head`

Display files in the **/data/** directory tree that are 25M or larger

`# find /data/ -size +25M -exec ls -l {} \; | sort -nr -k5`

Answer (score 0):

A handy interactive tool for checking what is using diskspace (and can cleanup while you're at it) is `ncdu` (i.e. ncurses `du`).

Install via apt on Debian/Ubuntu (should be in repos of most, if not all distros).

In your case (assuming your user has full read access), run it like this:

```
ncdu /data
```

It will take a while to scan, but then will display in order of size. You can drill down into dirs and delete files/dirs as you go.